# Como leer un archivo apartir de una linea y escribir otro apartir de esa misma linea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, filewriter, filereader

```py
print("Presiona: \n 1 - Para leer y traducir desde el inicio del archivo\n 2 - Para leer apartir de una linea especifica del archivo")
how_to_read = str(input())

if (how_to_read == "1"):
    read_mode = "w"
    total_previous_lines = 0 #Leera el archivo desde el principio
elif(how_to_read == "2"):
    read_mode = "a"
    with open('translated_file.xml') as last_translated_file:
        total_previous_lines = sum(1 for line in last_translated_file) - 1  #Cantidad de lineas, a las que les resto uno por la ultima linea que es vacia y debe reemplazar desde ella de ser el caso
        print(total_previous_lines)
else:
    print("No ha elegido ninguna de las opciones validas")
    read_mode = None

if(read_mode):
    with open("en-sentiment.xml", "r") as read_file:
        #NECESITO LEER "en-sentiment.xml" APARTIR DE total_previous_lines + 1 (osea la siguiente a la ultima que ya habia, para continuar...)

        with open("translated_file.xml", read_mode) as write_file:
            #NECESITO ESCRIBIR "translated_file.xml" APARTIR DE total_previous_lines + 1 (osea la siguiente a la ultima que ya habia, para continuar...)

            #Por cada linea del archivo que lee vamos a escribir el archivo con la funcion write 
            for line in read_file:
                print(repr(line))
```

Ese es mi codigo, y estaba teniendo problemas para leer los ficheros .xml apartir de esa `total_previous_lines`, ya que la sentencia `with open() as ..._file:` naturalmente lee desde el inicio iterando linea a linea, pero en este caso si el archivo ya existiese, si con el modo de apertura `a` quisiese escribir apartir de `total_previous_lines` tendria el problema de que empieza a iterar desde el principio.

Y con el modo de apertura `r` pasaria lo mismo en caso de querer leer desde `total_previous_lines` con un valor diferente de 0 (osea primera linea)

Comment: Prueba [leer desde líneas específicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-a-file-by-line-number) y [escribir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python) también en posiciones específicas.

Comment: @M.K Si vi eso, el unico problema es que yo necesitaba leer y escribir apartir de la linea especifica +1 y no solo esa linea especifica.

Answer (score 0):

Matías.

Puedes probar usar el método readlines: `last_translated_file.readlines()` de este modo te genera una lista donde cada elemente es una línea del archivo. Luego bastaría con conocer la línea en donde quieres empezar.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, y yo estoy usando el `with open("en-sentiment.xml", "r") as read_file:` para el caso donde busco una lectura, ademas tengo la variable `total_previous_lines` que es en donde ya se guardaria aquella linea en la que quiero empezar, por ese motivo hice lo de sumar y restar el 1 correspondientemente en mi code. Pero aun asi el problema concretamente que tengo y comentaba en la pregunta, es el de como hacer para pasarle al metodo `.readlines()` , en caso de hacerlo de ese modo, la linea de inicio que tengo ya almacenada en la variable `total_previous_lines` como muestro en el code.